# AngularJS - Creating a new row when using ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using a simple **ng-repeat** to generate a list of countries and their corresponding data. Within each list is a hidden row that can be expanded and collapsed.

I'm struggling to get this hidden row to appear at the bottom of each row from the `ng-repeat`.

**HTML:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
   <td>{{country.name}}</td>
   <td>{{country.population}}</td>
   <td>{{country.currency}}</td>
   <td>{{country.gpd}}</td>

   <tr>
        <p>Expand/collapse content</p>
   </tr>
</tr>
```

**Output:**

```
France     61.3     EUR    54
Germany    81.5     EUR    82
Spain      12.7     EUR    78
UK         51.3     GBR    64
Expand/collapse content
```

**Desired Output:**

```
France     61.3     EUR    54
Expand/collapse content

Germany    81.5     EUR    82
Expand/collapse content

Spain      12.7     EUR    78
Expand/collapse content

UK         51.3     GBR    64
Expand/collapse content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` as follow:

```
    <tr ng-repeat-start="country in countries">
       <td>{{country.name}}</td>
       <td>{{country.population}}</td>
       <td>{{country.currency}}</td>
       <td>{{country.gpd}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
       <td>Expand/collapse content</td>
    </tr>
```

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nYzjY/372/

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Thanks, do you have a working fiddle as this doesnt seem to work

Comment: Thanks, im using v1.1.5 of Angular, would ng-repeat-start/end work with this version?

Comment: Since it's not mentioned in the documentation of the 1.1.5 version (https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat), I think that won't work. By the way, I recommend you to migrate to the 1.2 version since the 1.1 versions were experimentals (see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration)

Comment: i would migrate, however ive read route and resource are separate libraries now, i'd rather use 1.1.5 to only have 1 http request

Answer (score 1):

You are repeating a `tr` and then you are inserting another `tr` after the repetition. Since you want both the `tr's` to be repeated. you should nest them in to one. e-g:

```
<div  ng-repeat="country in countries">
    <tr>
       <td>{{country.name}}</td>
       <td>{{country.population}}</td>
       <td>{{country.currency}}</td>
       <td>{{country.gpd}}</td>

       <tr>
            <p>Expand/collapse content</p>
       </tr>
    </tr>
    </div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://liveweave.com/G9m3KJ)

Comment: @default - Thanks, do you have a working fiddle as this doesnt seem to work

Comment: Thanks, im using v1.1.5 of Angular, would ng-repeat-start/end work with this version?